# Insert text in toggle button html-css

Tags: html, css

I have this.

[image]

[image]

I want this.

[image]

[image]

this is such a long code. I really dont want to post it. But here it is

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>check</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main2.css">
</head>
<body>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

now css code is:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
}
```

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
    .switch input {display:none;}

/* The slider */

```
 .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 36px;
  width: 60px;
  left:0px;
  bottom: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(120px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(120px);
  transform: translateX(120px);
}
```

i know it's such a long code . But very easy to understand. Thanks for helping.

Comment: what is this `<font color="white">`. You're already using css, why pollute content with presentational markup?

Comment: nothing.. ignore it. I was trying to figure out some way to solve it. forgot to edit while posting

Comment: someone will soon post an answer, but this toggle switch style is already available all over the internet eg - https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/
just take a look over the code and you'll understand it fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 34px;
}

 .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "aaa";
  height: 36px;
  width: 60px;
  left:0px;
  bottom: -1px;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}


input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}


input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(120px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(120px);
  transform: translateX(120px);
}

.text {
  color: white;
}

.text:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 25px;
  content: "Switch off";
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.text:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 25px;
  content: "Switch on";
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

input + .slider + .text:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
input + .slider + .text:before {
  opacity: 0;
}


input:checked + .slider + .text:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

input:checked + .slider + .text:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>check</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main2.css">
</head>
<body>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
</label>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1yymr2kx/5/

Just add `:after`element which changes content when checkbox is clicked.

```
.slider:after {
  content:'OFF';
  position:relative;
  padding:10px;
  padding-left:100px;
}

input:checked + .slider:after {
  content: 'ON';
  padding-left:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this with javascript

in body put this :

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="slider" id='onoff' data-onoff="on" >swithc off</div>
</label>
```

in css add to .slider

```
color:white; text-align:right;
```

and replace input:checked + .slider  with this :

```
 input:checked + .slider {
 background-color: #2196F3;
 text-align:left;
  }
```

embed a .js file and put this code inside it

```
var slider = document.getElementById('onoff');
slider.onclick = function () { 
var show = slider.getAttribute("data-onoff");

if(show=='on'){
slider.getElementById("content").innerHTML ="switch on";
slider.setAttribute("data-onoff","off");}


else {
slider.getElementById("content").innerHTML ="switch off";
slider.setAttribute("data-onoff","on");
 }  
   };
```

Comment: who rate this negative , are you ever try this ??